# Using a self join model in a has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a self join model `captain` on my `user` model. I'm having an issue using the captain in an has_one relationship with a `team` model, which already has a has_many relationship with the user model.

My **Team Model**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :teamname, :teamcolor, presence: true

  has_one  :captain, :class_name => "User"
   #, :through => :user
  has_many :users


  #after_save :set_default_captain

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :captain
end
```

My **User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :remember_token

  before_save {self.email = email.downcase }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                         format:{with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, 
                         uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true

  has_one :profile, inverse_of: :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :teammates, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "captain_id"

  belongs_to :captain, :class => "User"
  belongs_to :team


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team
end
```

I'm having the issue using `@team.captain`, as `captain_id` is in the User database table but it's retrieving the first user with the `team_id` equaling `@team.id. Using`has_one :captain, :through => :user` gives association error. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to specify `foreign_key` for the association.

```
has_one  :captain, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'captain_id'
```

Comment: is `has_one` preferred over `belongs_to` for self-joins?